# macos Django Can't find mysqlclient

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am Django 2.2.8 python3.7

I made a virtual environment of Django,I installed mysqlclient, too

This is all my bags，i have mysqlclient.

```
Package             Version
------------------- -------
asgiref             3.2.3  
Django              2.2.8  
django-filter       2.2.0  
djangorestframework 3.10.3 
mysqlclient         1.4.6  
pip                 19.0.3 
pytz                2019.3 
setuptools          40.8.0 
sqlparse            0.3.0
```

I didn't make any settings except database links

Here is the error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/a1/PycharmProjects/xuexi/xunilufei/lufei01/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 15, in <module>
    import MySQLdb as Database
  File "/Users/a1/PycharmProjects/xuexi/xunilufei/lufei01/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from . import _mysql
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/a1/PycharmProjects/xuexi/xunilufei/lufei01/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-37m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libmysqlclient.21.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/a1/PycharmProjects/xuexi/xunilufei/lufei01/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-37m-darwin.so
  Reason: image not found

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/a1/PycharmProjects/xuexi/xunilufei/lufei01/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/a1/PycharmProjects/xuexi/xunilufei/lufei01/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 357, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/Users/a1/PycharmProjects/xuexi/xunilufei/lufei01/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/a1/PycharmProjects/xuexi/xunilufei/lufei01/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/Users/a1/PycharmProjects/xuexi/xunilufei/lufei01/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/a1/PycharmProjects/xuexi/xunilufei/lufei01/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "/Users/a1/PycharmProjects/xuexi/xunilufei/lufei01/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 47, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "/Users/a1/PycharmProjects/xuexi/xunilufei/lufei01/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 117, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "/Users/a1/PycharmProjects/xuexi/xunilufei/lufei01/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 321, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/Users/a1/PycharmProjects/xuexi/xunilufei/lufei01/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 204, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "/Users/a1/PycharmProjects/xuexi/xunilufei/lufei01/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 28, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "/Users/a1/PycharmProjects/xuexi/xunilufei/lufei01/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 201, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/Users/a1/PycharmProjects/xuexi/xunilufei/lufei01/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 110, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/Users/a1/PycharmProjects/xuexi/xunilufei/lufei01/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 20, in <module>
    ) from err
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module.
Did you install mysqlclient?
```

I really can't find the problem

Thank you for any help
I didn't make any settings
I didn't make any settings except database links

```
DATABASES = {
   'default': {
          'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
          'NAME': 'jialuffei',                       
          'USER': 'root',                       
          # 'PASSWORD': 'mysql',                   
          'PASSWORD': '060606',                   
          'HOST': '',                           
          'PORT': '',                           
          'OPTIONS': {
             'autocommit': True,
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This may not be it, but to be sure, do you have the database engine added and configured in your settings.py? My example is an older version of Django (1.10) but still applies to your version, and I remember having issues and having to configure the engine.

I suspect you wouldn't even be getting that error if it wasn't configured so perhaps this answer is unnecessary, but again I'm just going through the thought process.

```
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#databases
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'db_name',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '3306',
        'USER': 'db_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'db_password',
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use mysql connector instead of `django.db.backends.mysql`. You can check out the mysql configuration [here](https://pypi.org/project/mysqlclient/)

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'mysql.connector.django',
        'NAME': 'db_name',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '3306',
        'USER': 'db_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'db_password',
    }
}
```